# Operation `mov [esp - 4], eax` Adds Additional Byte

Tags: assembly, intel, cpu-registers, machine-code

I was doing some experimenting with machine code in MSVC++ and created a function that would allow me to build mov operations around registers with signed displacements.  All went well until I had my function build off of `mov [esp-4], eax`.  Suddenly, my program started crashing.  After having a peek in the disassembly, I noticed something rather strange.  For this `mov` op dereferencing an offset from the `ESP` register, an additional byte was being placed between the parameter byte and the signed displacement.  This byte always seemed to be 0x24.  So out of curiosity, I disassembled the following `__asm` block and got some interesting results:

```
mov [eax - 4], eax
mov [ecx - 4], eax
mov [edx - 4], eax
mov [ebx - 4], eax
mov [esp - 4], eax
mov [ebp - 4], eax
mov [esi - 4], eax
mov [edi - 4], eax
```

The machine code translated the above into:

```
89 40 FC
89 41 FC
89 42 FC
89 43 FC
89 44 24 FC      <--- WAT!
89 45 FC
89 46 FC
89 47 FC
```

I typed hex 24 into Windows calculator and switched it to binary.  The result was `00100100`.  What this *appears* to be is two dummy bits followed by the `ESP` register twice.

Can anyone shed some light on why this is happening?  I think this goes beyond weird quirks of the MS C++ compiler and straight into the realm of legacy functionality from the '70s or '80s ('90s?), but I can't find any online references as to why `ESP` is an exception for this flavor of `mov` operation.   Thanks!

Comment: There are actually quite a few foibles of this kind in the x86 instruction encoding. For example, look at `xchg eax, ecx` compared to `xchg ebx, ecx` or `add eax, 256` compared to `add ebx, 256`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`[esp]` can not be encoded using a `modr/m` byte only, it needs a `SIB` byte. See *Table 2-2. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte* in the intel instruction set reference.
The `44` value of modr/m encodes that the other operand is `eax` and that a `SIB` byte and a displacement byte follows. `SIB` value of `24` encodes `[esp]`, see *Table 2-3. 32-Bit Addressing Forms with the SIB Byte*.

The `SIB` can encode all the other variants too, but since that is 1 byte longer, the assembler doesn't use that form. Here is the list for reference:

```
89 44 20 FC mov [eax-0x4],eax
89 44 21 FC mov [ecx-0x4],eax
89 44 22 FC mov [edx-0x4],eax
89 44 23 FC mov [ebx-0x4],eax
89 44 24 FC mov [esp-0x4],eax
89 44 25 FC mov [ebp-0x4],eax
89 44 26 FC mov [esi-0x4],eax
89 44 27 FC mov [edi-0x4],eax
```

This, by itself, shouldn't cause your crash, but randomly trying to overwrite stuff in memory may.

Comment: This makes perfect sense!  I think it's fair time I brush up on my machine code after reading this.  Thanks for the help! I snuck the special case in my code and the crash went away.  So I'm a bit concerned about your last statement.  I did modify the way my offsets were calculated so it is possible I was originally off by a word (which would cause the crash), but that seems fixed.  I'm going to run some more tests to be sure, though.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the second byte of the instruction, you see an incrementing sequence of 3 bit values, 0 through 7, which represent register operands, except for 4. The value of 4 is used for more generic operand types and Intel chose to put esp in the generic list, since ebp is used more often for stack based references.